# Gimp plugin: using the 'ink' tool

Tags: gimp

The gimp API contains a method to use the 'brush' :http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimppainttools.html

```
gimp_paintbrush_default
```

what is the equivalent method for the 'ink' tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. 
It is currently not possible to progrmaticaly use the inktool. 
This is due to this tool needing some timing information (mouse speed), as opposed to just stroke coordinates, as the other tools (without dynamics) do.

So, this is a missing feature - and would have to be implemented in GIMP. As are PDB calls for painting that could emulate the painting dynamics or GIMP's animated brushes.

Another missing feature also blocks a workaround: it is possible to create a selection or a vectors and use `gimp-edit-stroke` - and the `edit stroke` can use the Ink Tool -  but it is not possible to *select* the inktool.  So, your plug-in could present a gtk dialog and ask the user to select the inktool in the UI before proceeding. (This uses a constant speed for the stroke, though)